# Como Mockear Webclient utilizando mockito en mi api-rest con spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Tengo en mi aplicación una clase con varios metodos el cual solo indico aqui el `GET`,`DELETE`, donde ese metodo llama a una api-rest externa para recoger información.
Solo tengo un END-POINT en el controlador y la clase que describo a continuación.

```
public class CallApiRest {

    private String url;
    private String path;

    private WebClient webClient;


    public ResponseEntity<Flux<CandidateRequestAssigned>> get (String url,String path){
         webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();

        return  ResponseEntity.ok( webClient.get()
                .uri(path)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("HTTP Status 400 Bad request");
                })
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,response -> {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("HTTP Status 500 error");  
                })
                .bodyToFlux(CandidateRequestAssigned.class)
                .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofMillis(2000))));

    }

    public ResponseEntity<Mono<CandidateRequestAssigned>> delete (String url,String path ,String id){
        webClient = WebClient.create(url);

        return  ResponseEntity.ok( webClient.delete()
                .uri(path + "/" + id)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("HTTP Status 400 Bad request");
                })
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,response -> {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("HTTP Status 500 error"); 
                })
                .bodyToMono(CandidateRequestAssigned.class));

    }

}
```

No consigo con JUNIT5-MOCKITO hacer el test de los metodos que indico arriba. a la hora de hacer una llamada en un test ejemplo:

```
**CallApiRest callApiRest.get();**

**LLamada al end-point del controlador:** 
@GetMapping("/callApiGet")
    public ResponseEntity<Flux<CandidateRequestAssigned>> callApiGet(@Valid @RequestBody CallApiRequest callApiRequest) {
        CallApiRest callApiRest = new CallApiRest();
        return  callApiRest.get(callApiRequest.getUrl(),callApiRequest.getPath());
    }
```